# show action bar after activity animation completes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am using the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055984/display-page-from-bottom-to-top) to animate an activity into life. But I don't want the action bar to show until after the animation is complete. If I set action bar to hide and then to show in onResume, it's as if I never hid it. does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: sounds like you need to set a callback on that animation for once it's finished then you want to show the actionbar, take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386116/set-animation-listener-to-activity-animations

Answer (score 0):

Create an animation and set a callback:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.an_animation);
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
   public void onAnimationEnd() {
       // code to show actionbar
   }
   public void onAnimationStart() {}
   public void onAnimationRepeat() {}
}
```

and then proceed to add the animation to the view and start it

**EDIT:** I just read you meant to animate an `Activity`, not a `View`. Since `Activity` does not provides any method to set animation callbacks, you could create an `AyncTask`, in the `onCreate` method of the second `Activity`, that will wait the same time as the animation. If the animation goes for 500ms, then your `AsyncTask` will wait 500ms and then shows the `ActionBar`:

```
public class SecondActivity {

    private ActionBar bar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        bar = getActionBar();
        bar.hide();

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {

            @Override
            public void doInBackground(Void params...) {

                Thread.sleep(500);
                bar.show();

                return null;
             }

       }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you please elaborate on "proceed to add animation to the view"? I am starting a new activity. Did you see the link I provided under "here"? Thanks.