# be aware of window animation start In android

Tags: android, android-animation

When I start a new Activity using `startActivity(intent, activityoptions.toBundle)` or `overridePendingTransition`

How can I know when the animation start?

for example, is there a method like

`onWindowAnimationStart` to tell me that the animation is start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not have any. I think you need to create your own custom method with custom listener to achieve that.

UPDATE

I just found this : [Set animation listener to Activity animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386116/set-animation-listener-to-activity-animations)

You may want to try those answers, and yes, you must create your own method.