# Change black color when scale first activity during transition

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to change the black color (outside activity) when scale activity during transition (eg: I want to make change it to white). You can see the black color in the image below

[image]

Here is my code

**slide_up.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/activity_transition_time"
    >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:toAlpha="1"/>
</set>
```

**scale_down.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >
    <scale
        android:duration="@integer/activity_transition_time"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%p"
        android:pivotY="50%p"
        android:toYScale="0.8" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0.6"
        />
</set>
```

**FirstActivity.java**

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.anim_scale_down);
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Can I do it or is there any other approach? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: try adding `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` to your theme.

Comment: @KaranMer when adding `android:windowIsTranslucent` the black become transparent (and I still don't know how to change it to another color)

Comment: i implement one example but in this example new activity come bottom to up and current activity show as it is if you want example i can provide you @PhanVanLinh

Comment: @MohammadAli do you scale down the first activity?

Comment: not sure but please try this line **`<translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="400"/>`** in `scale_down.xml` file but first comment your code.

Comment: can you try and use just `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` when you add windowistranslucent

Comment: and also paste this line **`<translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />`** in `slide_up.xml`

Comment: @MohammadAli in your demo it working right? black color will become which color? I still can not make it work @@

Comment: in my example you show your previous activity As it is. not show any color

Comment: @MohammadAli I don't understand much. Can you give me your example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a normal animation instead for the overridePendingTransition and then you can control the animation and do what you need.
[Set animation listener to Activity animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386116/set-animation-listener-to-activity-animations)